# How do I mark a package download if the individual items (within the package) are listed beside it?

Tags: icons, download

We are having a dilemma and I thought to ask the experts.

We offer video, xml and package (< video plus XML) downloads.
If the user downloads the video, a green marker appears showing that it has been downloaded. When someone downloads the XML, the same thing happens. Now, the point of contention is the package download. I think that if the user clicks on download package, only the package icons should change to green. My coworkers think that all three should be marked: Video, xml and package.

Which one is the best way?

Answer (score 4):

None of the above. Just list the video and XML, each having a green marker displayed when downloaded - like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffi7HE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options you listed, it is probably more sensible to only mark the package as being downloaded.  Otherwise, your interface will suggest that three things are being downloaded, which is only likely to be confusing.

That said, I recommend the approach that Benny suggested in his answer.  This has the advantage of communicating to the user exactly what it is that they're doing.

Comment: Thanks for both responses. Benny, I totally agree with the suggestion, unfortunately, we can't change the interface just yet.

Answer (score 0):

We are building something similar,

I would suggest to slightly dim down the other options when the package are chosen. When someone wants the whole package, the other options becomes obsolete.

This would require a third state: Disabled / Dimmed down

The question to answer next is how long they should be dimmed down - maybe until the package has started downloading?

A third functionality would be to cancel the download on a second click, but this might be confusing or overthinking from my side (in all cases, test)